# Moving an ImageView on the screen dynamically in android

Tags: android, mouse, imageview, mousemove, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to simulate the movements of a mouse cursor in my application. I initially put a cursor image to xml file and I initialize this imageview in onCreate() method. I'm planning to change the position of the cursor image when user touchs to the screen until action up event occurs. Also, activity class implements onTouchListener and overrides onTouch() method. However, I couldn't change the position of the image on the layout programmatically. Therefore, I need to change/set the position of image dynamically on the screen. Is there any way to implement such movement in android?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: are you trying to make the mouse cursor follow a finger? or do you simply want to move it along a pre-designated path while a finger is on the screen?

Comment: It's not required to follow the finger of the user. I simply try to move the image through the screen dynamically within the method of onTouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using following code blocks

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageVieww);
imageView.setX(x);
imageView.setY(y);
imageView.invalidate();
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If setting the position is all you want, then can be done by various APIs;

1.

```
mMyImg.setX();
mMyImg.setY();
```

2.

```
mMyImg.setLeft();
mMyImg.setTop();
```

3.

```
mMyImg.setTranslationX();
mMyImg.setTranslationY();
```

However, there are methods which can do this w/ animation as well. Have a look at:

4.

```
mMyImg.animate().translationX();
mMyImg.animate().trnaslationY();
```

or
5.

```
mMyImg.animate().translationXBy();
mMyImg.animate().translationYBy();
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) will have MotionEvent as parameter.

that MotionEvent  will have MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE actions.
use those and update the position on the cursor image position.

Comment: I successfully did these things. I'm not asking motion event or action methods. I'm asking how to change/set the position of an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

You'll use the Translate Animation. You can tell it where to move to and from, and how long to take doing so.

Here is a nice [tutorial for Animations](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/), it includes some translate ones.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not get an answer you can try:

```
image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX() - 50,
                    (int) me.getRawY() - 30, 0, 0);
```